# TFS Alert Based On A Tag

Tags: tagging

I'm stuck and can't find info anywhere - does anyone know if there is a way to create a TFS Alert based on a tag placed on Workitem? Or should I just build an SSRS report based on the tables?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a TFS server-side plugin to send email alerts based on work-item's tag.

There is a user-voice request for: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6059328-use-tags-in-alerts